# Loop over rows of csv.DictReader more than once

Tags: python, csv

I open a file and read it with `csv.DictReader`.  I iterate over it twice, but the second time nothing is printed.  Why is this, and how can I make it work?

```
with open('MySpreadsheet.csv', 'rU') as wb:
    reader = csv.DictReader(wb, dialect=csv.excel)
    for row in reader:
        print row

    for row in reader:
        print 'XXXXX'

# XXXXX is not printed
```

Comment: Nope! file objects in python are generators, so you have to reopen the file to loop more than once.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes good suggestion, but in my real-world example, I need to build a dict from each operation within the first `for`, then iterate over the reader again and compare with the dict.

Comment: in real-world examples, files are read only once, normally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You read the entire file the first time you iterated, so there is nothing left to read the second time.  Since you don't appear to be using the csv data the second time, it would be simpler to count the number of rows and just iterate over that range the second time.

```
import csv
from itertools import count

with open('MySpreadsheet.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel)
    row_count = count(1)

    for row in reader:
        next(count)
        print(row)

for i in range(row_count):
    print('Stack Overflow')
```

If you need to iterate over the raw csv data again, it's simple to open the file again.  Most likely, you should be iterating over some data you stored the first time, rather than reading the file again.

```
with open('MySpreadsheet.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)

with open('MySpreadsheet.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel)

    for row in reader:
        print('Stack Overflow')
```

If you don't want to open the file again, you can seek to the beginning, skip the header, and iterate again.

```
with open('MySpreadsheet.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)

    f.seek(0)
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        print('Stack Overflow')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of dictionaries, each dictionary representing a row in your file, and then count the length of the list, or use list indexing to print each dictionary item.

Something like:

```
with open('YourCsv.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    rowslist = list(reader)

for i in range(len(rowslist))
    print(rowslist[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

add a `wb.seek(0)` (goes back to the start of the file) and `next(reader)` (skips the header row) before your second loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try store the dict in list and output

```
input_csv = []
with open('YourCsv.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        input_csv.append(row)

for row in input_csv:
    print(row)

for row in input_csv:
    print(row)
```